# How to use HTTP Handler to make a client2client communication?

Tags: handler

I'm new to Web programming! I try to make an app (something like Client to Client communication with C# Handlers and jQuery).

I.E.: When 1Client make a click on his clientSide(browser), there paints one point, and on the same time the 2Client sees what 1Client did. And, in turn, where 2Client make a click on his browser, there paints one point, and the 1Client also sees what 2Client did.

I could done already the configuration of IIS, I made an simple show Hello World and it run OK. And, further, what should i done....

Can you advice me, please, with some exemples, or tutorials, how to do this job.

Sorry for my questions which seems to be not studied.

Comment: Normally development questions are migrated to StackOverflow. But this question would be considered low quality and immediately closed there so I cannot migrate it there and will just close it here.